# x86-64 mechanism for automatic bounds checking

Tags: x86-64

Is there any scheme in usermode x64 for the hardware to automatically apply bounds checking on each memory load and store, without explicit instrumentation from the compiler? I also do not want to rely on OS support (e.g. mprotect system call).

`<begin: enforce all accesses within 0x10000000-0x10000100>
...
mov ___, ___ #hardware automatically performs range check
...
<end enforcement>`

AFAIK, Intel MPX requires explicit bndcl/bndcu instructions before each checked memory access.

Comment: you can handle the signals that you get when you try to dereference bad addresses... like a debugger does; but I assure you this is folly

Comment: In what bounds, just "valid memory" or "still inside the object that it's supposed to be in"?

Comment: I have a way to compute the upper and lower virtual addresses, and I wish to force the protected code to only access within that range.

Answer (score 3):

No. For the simple reason that CPUs are not crystal balls and the information *what* the bounds are have to come from *somewhere*. And it is the task of the program to determine that *"what"* and be the *"somewhere"*.

Comment: I understand. I am willing to provide the bounds before the protected code. I just do not wish to instrument each memory access within the protected code.

Comment: @rsinha: Computers are deterministic. If you know the bounds and the formula by which addresses are generated from the index, you should proof mathematically, that given that formula and the bounds no address outside these bounds will be generated. With such a proof at hand you can be 100% sure, that no OOB access will happen. This kind of provability is at the heart of the memory safety of programming languages like Rust, Haskell and similar, which are strictly statically type checked. If the compiler can prove at compile time that memory accesses stay within bounds it will omit bounds checks

Comment: Type systems for such analysis are excellent --- definitely, Rust can enforce that memory accesses will be within bounds of an array. However, if I want to prove or enforce (at runtime) that a memory operation will only access the top half of the array --- basically any finer grained control --- it would require more heavyweight proof techniques such as dependent types.